# Hadoop Mapreduce performance improvement using fields projection

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce

We are planning to implement a `data projection layer` which is going to select only `subset` of fields from set of data fields to reduce the amount of data sent to map-reduce processing.

`Question`: Is this approach is going to improve performance of the map-reduce job? When compared to the selecting only specific fields using `subString()` in mapper? This is definitely going to save on storage though.

We are going to test it with some sample data, but technically what would be the suggestion? Does Hadoop handle it itself?

Example:

**Input data**: `sensor_id, location, day, time, month, year, temperature, humidity, quality, wind_direction, wind_velocity`

**Output of projection**: `year, temperature`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you implementing this projection as a record reader?. or in which phase of mapreduce ?

Comment: this is going to be a map reduce job itself which will run only before the actual job is run. The o/p of this projection will be sent to hdfs as input to the actual map-reduce job.